# If $X$ is a non-negative random variable with finite expectation, does the sequence $X_n = X1_{X \leq n}$ converge to $X$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I thought this was immediate, but I am worried about the case when $X$ may be unbounded for some event $\omega$. In particular, I tried showing that for any $\omega \in \Omega$, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n(\omega) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X(\omega) 1_{X \leq n} (\omega) = X(\omega) 1_{\Omega}(\omega) = X(\omega)$$ but I am not sure if the second equality is valid. Is the result true? Ultimately, I want to show $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, but I was not successful proving this directly.

Comment: If $X : \Omega\to\mathbb R$, then $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ for _every_ $\omega$. If $X : \Omega\to\bar{\mathbb R}$, then $X_n(\omega)$ is not defined for those $\omega$ for which $X(\omega) = +\infty$.

Comment: Yes but the problem doesn't specify that the range of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$. It simply states that $X \geq 0$. I am worried about the case when $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: $\mathsf{E}X<\infty$ implies that $X<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: If you are only given $X\ge 0$, then the information is simply not sufficient.

Comment: $X \geq 0$ with $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$

Comment: You should have said that before! Then the $X_n$ are defined a.s. and $X_n\to X$ a.s.

Comment: Sorry it is in the title of the post! Should have specified that in the text.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you should have. You are fine now, right?

Comment: Yes the finite expectation should guarantee boundedness almost surely as noted by @d.k.o.

Comment: Actually you can not say it that way. But yes, $P(X=\infty) = 0$.